# XCode: application->iPod Run/Build not uploading app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode says it builds and finished running on my iPod except the app is not on my iPod.

Using Xcode 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2

also note that the xcode"log navigator" shows a number of the build/debug instances with status wheels spinning.

On the organizer I get the following repeating:

```
Sun Jan  1 15:34:53 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[16] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
Sun Jan  1 15:35:53 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iTunes. Killing connection
```

I have disconnected, closed programs, rebooted the Mac, and still get the same problems.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this with another iPod/iPhone to check if the problem is a soft corruption or a hardware related issue with your iPod (or the USB connection cable)? Reading the error log that you posted it seems to be a hardware related problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**note:** This answer assumes you will be able to run your app on an iPod touch. If you are using a resource not available on an iPod touch, like GPS for example, you may be being prevented from running your app by a GPS device requirement(see required device capabilities).

This sounds like a classic example of trying to run on an iPod touch 1st or 2nd gen without jumping through the apple imposed hoops. (Says finished running but never runs, logs are just spinning indicators.)

To build for these older devices, you must jump through these hoops:

How to add support for `iOS 4.2`, `armv6` in `Xcode 4.2` and up:

Set your deployment target to 4.2 or earlier:
[image]
Modify Architectures to include `armv6` like so:
1)Select Other,
[image]
2) Click on the "+" button,
[image]
3) Type in "armv6",
[image]
4) Click done.

Then remove armv7 from required device capabilities by clicking the "-" button in that row.

[image]
I personally use this method constantly to run apps on my iPod touch 2nd gen with the newest Xcode.

In fact the project that I used for this example now runs on that iPod.

Comment: I was struggling with this problem from last one week and i tried everything and finally when i saw your answer and thought let me remove armv7 from required device capabilities and it worked. Big thanks to you.