# Cannot debug iOS project on device

Tags: ios, xcode, device

Weird error is occurring to me, I followed the guide from apple, to provisioning portal to test the project on a real device, create a certificate, add a device an appID and then the  provision file.
Edited all the code signing identity settings to the new iphone developer provision file, and tried to run on my device.
The base of my SDK is 4.2,my device is 4.2 as well, but when i click the run button, its compile all the files, give me the build succeded message but even install on my device, its like none device was connected....

Comment: Whats the error your getting if any? Whats the end result when you run the project?

Comment: If you use ARMv6 device (old iPhones and iPod touches) - you need to apply tricks when using Xcode 4.2. It does not support old hardware out of box - requires additional steps.

Comment: Check the Xcode Organizer (Window->Organizer) - once the device is connected, does it show a green dot in front of the device name?

Comment: What Till says -- open the Organizer and see if your device is being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is appearing here:(In the place of "iPhone 5.0 Simulator") Then your device is correctly connected.

[image: Image of Xcode scheme bar]

And if your device says "Finished Running" When it hasn't even started running then as 'AlexeyVMP' said there are a few more steps to get your app to run on an ARMV6 device (usually the only reason anyone is still on iOS 4.2 these days)

Basically you have to add `armv6` to the `architectures` in the project pane and remove `armv7` from the `required devices capabilities` in the `info.plist` of your project.

You can see [screenshots of these steps at this stackoverflow question in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8697335/927947).