# How can I test app on older iPhone 3G with iOS v 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, testing, ios4, ios-provisioning

I  have been testing my app on my iPhone 4S and my wife's iPhone 3GS.  I would also like to test it on the older iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1 (the highest version it will support).

When I connect the 3G to my Mac and attempt to provision it, I get two error messages:

**Could Not Support Development**

and

**Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version**

I am using the latest version of xCode (v. 4.4.1).

Is there some place to find the missing 'software image' in order to test my app on the 3G and older iOS devices?

If not, how does one know what devices the app will work with?

I do note that the newer iPhones that run iOS5 and above also support Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). I have checked the ARC button whenever I created a new project. Does one have to abandon ARC if one wants their app to work on an older pre iOS5-capable device?

...Dale

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some place to find the missing 'software image'?

I believe you can download it through iTunes by clicking restore in the device's summary page and then searching for the `*.ipsw` file. iTunes might even share the image once it is downloaded automatically.

> Does one have to abandon ARC if one wants their app to work on an
>   older pre iOS5-capable device?

Not in entirety. iOS 4.2 supports the vast majority of `ARC`, But it does not support `weak` references.

Also, there are a few hoops you must jump through to target. I have an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8697335/927947) that outlines them (with screenshots).

I know for a fact that Xcode 4.4.1 can use an iOS 4.2.1 device as a target, since I can test on a second generation iPod touch running 4.2.1.

Finally, If you are not able to obtain a software image, you could try adding your device by UDID directly on the provisioning portal through developer.apple.com.(The old fashioned way)